# How can i make this reset button to reset this Questions?

Tags: reactjs, state, toggle, react-props

I have an application with the parent component

Parent component

```
 function App() {
     const [text, setText] = useState(' ');
     const outputRef = useRef();
     const resetRef = useRef()

const resetBtn = ()=>{
// Reset the output field
setText('');
// Reset the button states

}
 return (

      <div className="resetIcon" onClick={resetBtn}>
        <img src={resetIcon} alt="Reset icon for reset the game" 
          className='resetToggle' ref={resetRef}/>
      </div>
      <input type="text" 
            value={text} 
            className='display_text'
            ref={outputRef}
            readOnly
       />
      <div className="flex">
      <PaperLetter handleInnerText={handleInnerText}>teeth.</PaperLetter>
      <PaperLetter handleInnerText={handleInnerText}>brush</PaperLetter>
      <PaperLetter handleInnerText={handleInnerText}>my</PaperLetter>
      <PaperLetter handleInnerText={handleInnerText}>i</PaperLetter>
    </div>
```

Child Components
I want if I click on the reset button, then it should be able to change the clicked state triggering the addition and subtraction of the className

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

import { useState,useRef } from 'react';

export default function PaperLetter(props) {
const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
const letterRef = useRef();


const btnClicked =()=>{
    //Change the className of the btn click to active
    setClick(true);
    //Get the value of the letter btns click
    const getValue = letterRef.current.innerText;
    
    props.handleInnerText(getValue);
}

    return (
        <p className={click ? 'letter clicked': 'letter'} onClick={btnClicked} ref={letterRef} >{props.children}
        </p>
    )
}
```

I want to toggle the clicked state in the child component even though the resetBtn is in the parent component

[Link to the app :](https://assessment-test.netlify.app)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing this.

**In the App component:**

Use a new useState hook for saving the clicked words:

```
const [clickedWords, setClickedWords] = useState([]);
```

Create a new method for adding a single word:

```
const setClickedWord = clickedWord => setClickedWords(prevState => [...prevState, clickedWord]);
```

Pass `clickedWords` and `setClickedWord` as props to `PaperLetter.`

**In the PaperLetter Component:**

Get the new props: `const { children, clickedWords, setClickedWord } = props;`

Update the `btnClicked` method:

```
const btnClicked =()=>{
    setClickedWord(children)
    const getValue = letterRef.current.innerText;
    props.handleInnerText(getValue);
}
```

Update the className:

`className={clickedWords.includes(props.children) ? 'letter clicked': 'letter'}`

Of course there are alternatives for this, you could use a Context, you could create an array of words with ids to prevent duplicated selected words, you may create a new Intermediate component to extract this from the App components itself, etc.

Comment: Can you buttress more on this

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand exactly what your goal is. What I understood is that you want that when you click on the resetIcon (which calls the resetBtn function), this will toggle the clicked class on... all the child PaperLetter components? Or in a specific one?
What I suggested is that you create a state in the parent component.

My suggestion was adding a new state: const [resetClicked, setResetClicked] = useState(false) in the parent component. Then pass it by props to the children. And change the state to true inside the resetBtn function.

Comment: The app link is not working, could you fix it? Also, have at look at this: https://codesandbox.io/s/the-paperletter-example-5pzee?file=/src/App.js I tried to replicate more or less what I understood you want, correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: A link to the github repo: https://github.com/JoshuaOyewole/Nominis-assesment/tree/main/src

Comment: I want if a user clicks on the reset button, it should reset the class states and also reset the answer output to the initial state.    const resetBtn = ()=>{
    // Reset the output field
    setText('');
    // Reset the button clasess is the issue
    
  }  The reset function is in the Parent component(App.js) and there is already a state in the child component handling

Comment: toggling of class state based on onClick event. So I can I reset the class states to default when a resetBtn is fired from the parent component?

Comment: New link to the app: https://assessment-test.netlify.app

Comment: I updated my answer, please take a look.

Comment: Let me check it out